# What browsers support the input attribute - multiple

Tags: html, css, input

I'm integrate [this plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Overview) and his file input doesnt have multi file selection. So I added multiple attribute, but I just wonder if there is some browser or other thing(OS maybe) that doesnt support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many don't... see this link for discussion

http://ajaxian.com/archives/input-typefile-multiple-now-in-a-real-browser

Googling around it appears FF 3.6, Safari 4, and Chrome (not sure) support it. IE definitely doesn't and Opera might not.

Comment: So how all the uploading plugins does it?

Comment: If you want to do IE, you have to substitute in a flash implementation. Some plugins do that automatigically, others dont

Comment: But so far flash(i.e. SWFUpload) only crash my IE browser. =\

Comment: Dunno, sorry, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798171/use-jquery-swf-plugin-in-jsp looks promising

Answer (score 1):

According to W3Schools.com the multiple attribute is now supported in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari, and IE version 10.

Answer (score 0):

These are the Browsers and OS that don't support multiple file upload.

As of now (2017-04-13) [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=multiple) states:

**Not** Supported:

- Opera Mini on Android
- Android Browser
- Blackberry Browser
- Opera (37) for Android
- Chrome 57 on Android 4.x and below
- Firefox (52) for Android
- IE Mobile 11
- UC Browser 11 for Android
- Samsung Internet 4

Supported:

- IE from Version 10 (2012-09-04)
- MS Edge from Version 12 (2015-07-29)
- Firefox from Version 3.6 (2010-01-21)
- Chrome from Version 5 (2010-05-25)
- Safari from Version 4 (2009-06-08)
- Opera from Version 11.5 (2011-06-28)
- Safari + Chrome for iOS 6.0-6.1 (2013-01-28)
- Chrome 57 for Android (2017-03-27) on Android 5.x (not below)
- QQ Browser 1.2 (2017-01-01)